# Java JTextArea handling undisplayable ASCII sequences

Tags: java, swing, ascii, jtextarea

Streaming the output of a Linux command to a JTextArea. How can I handle the ASCII sequences. The sequences would normally be used to highlight text within a shell environment.

The JTEXTAREA looks like this:

```
ls -altr
drwx------  2 user    80 2009-11-25 07:23 [01;34mDocuments[00m
drwxr-xr-x  2 user    48 2009-11-25 07:23 [01;34mbin[00m
-rw-r--r--  1 user  1177 2009-11-25 07:23 [00m.bashrc[00m
drwx------  8 user   608 2009-11-25 07:23 [01;34m.[00m
drwxr-xr-x 88 user  2096 2011-03-09 08:47 [01;34m..[00m
-rw-------  1 user   472 2011-03-12 11:38 [00m.bash_history[00m
```

Where as it I should strip or deal with the strange ASCII sequences '[01;34m'. I can't filters char's because it's a sequences of chars.

Idea's ?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't filters char's because it's a sequences of chars.

You can use a [Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). A String of characters to be added to the Document is passed to the filter. You can remove any character from the string before updating the document.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI escape sequences start with `<esc>[` and end with `m` - you can filter them

Answer (score 0):

That seams to be color escape sequences.
There must be some option to disable colors in the `ls` listing, like `--color=never`.

And maybe `--hide-control-chars` to avoid non graphic characters.